# When the tinymce linked to a nullable-textarea is left empty, on submitting the form the UI becomes unresponsive in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am new to this forum. Please help me out with this problem.

When the tinymce editor linked to a nullable-textarea in my form is left empty, on submitting the form, the UI becomes unresponsive in Internet Explorer 9 and an empty text node appears. I can edit the text node as well.

I remove the tinymce editor instance linked with the textarea on success of the ajaxform request, using `jQuery("#textAreaI").tinymce().remove();`. And I have checked that it is getting removed by checking `tinyMCE.activeEditor == null`

My page also has other text areas linked with tinymce editors. And, everywhere when i submit the form with empty textarea, I face the similar problem.

It is working fine in firefox and chrome.